# React webpack create bundle with separated react

Tags: reactjs, build, webpack, production-environment

is possible to configure webpack to not compile react inside bundle file? I would like to have more react applications in one page and I would like to load react library only once to get smallest size. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In same situation I created final bundle with all small "applications" + React bundled once.

```
// components/index.js (webpacks entry point)
require("expose?React!react");
require("expose?MarketProductListing!./MarketProductListing");
require("expose?ProductDetail!./ProductDetail");
require("expose?MarketSearch!./MarketSearch");
```

Then, I include bundled JS via `<script/>` tag.

```
<script src="js/components.bundle.js"></script>
```

Now, I can access `React, MarketProductListing, ...` components in JS and render them where needed.

As you see, I use `expose-loader` for Webpack.

Webpack config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

const js_dir = path.join(__dirname, 'src');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: {
    components: path.join(js_dir, 'components'),
  },
  output: {
    path: js_dir,
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'es6-promise': 'es6-promise',
      'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loaders: ['babel'] }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  }
};
```

Comment: can you show me your production webpack config please?

Comment: added Webpack config

Comment: If you are doing this all from a single project, I don't see what you gain by doing this. If you are doing this from multiple projects, you would be better off marking React as a peerDependency and just marking your alternate projects as modules.